# Beanstalk app not found on my Amazon Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running two beanstalk apps in my AWS management console. I just signed into my account and I can no longer find my app. I am successfully able to push new code to my apps and the logged in account has a successful Route 53 setup to one of my apps, so I know I'm in the correct account.

My question is, what happened and how can I check where my beanstalk account is? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you chose the right region from the drop down on the top right of the aws console?

Comment: Ugh. I'm embarrassed. I was in the wrong region. All works now.